# log4net generates wrong log file name after rolling log files

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

Basically I have this config for log4net:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion" />
  </root>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion" type="Namespace.RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs/%property{LogName}/log.%property{ServiceName}-PID-%processid_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,ffff} [%thread] %exception - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Now I have a problem. Everytime log4net rolls log file, it doesn't change the date part of log file. For example if today's log file is - **log.MyServiceName-PID-1234_20131208.log**, tomorrow after rolling the file, name of the file won't change, so I will end up having a rolled back log file and active log file like this

1. **log.QAService-PID-17584_20131208.log**
2. **log.QAService-PID-17584_20131208.log2013Dec08**

What I would like to have is

1. **log.QAService-PID-17584_20131209.log** - active log file
2. **log.QAService-PID-17584_20131208.log2013Dec08** - rolled back

Now I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090788/log4net-generating-wrong-log-file-name), but it didn't help me. In particular, if I remove date pattern from file, and set **preserveLogFileNameExtension** to **true**, I can't see date part on active log file anymore. If I go further and set **staticLogFileName** to **false**, I don't have active log files anymore, instead active log files are having the rolled back log file name pattern.

What am I missing here? How can I have right log file names generated after roll back.

I'm using log4net version 1.2.10.0. Unfortunately I can't upgrade it to newer version.

**Update**
This is custom implementation of RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion. It just cleans up old rolled back files after log file rolling took place.

```
public class RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion :RollingFileAppender
    {
        private IFileBurner m_fileBurner;
        private const int checkMinutes = 1664;
        public RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion()
        {
            m_fileBurner = FileBurner.Instance;

        }

        protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
        {
            base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();

            string path = base.File;
            string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

            IDeletionRequirements requirements = new DeletionRequirements();
            requirements.CheckEveryMinutes = checkMinutes;
            requirements.DayLimit = MaxSizeRollBackups;
            requirements.Directories = new List<string> { directoryPath };

            m_fileBurner.ClearLogFiles(requirements);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the type Namespace.RollingAppenderWithDeletion, which is definately not a standard appender. Try use the type log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender and see if that works. When you use your custom appender you need to post some code, or find why the filename code is not called.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, edited the post. As you can see nothing really fancy in custom implementation. All it does, is cleaning up the old rolled log files.

Comment: Try use the standard to check if the dates are correct. If so, you need to debug your RollingFileAppenderWithDeletion. However if I look to your extention of the RollingFileAppender, I serieusly doubt if it adds the function you want. Try to attach a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: I changed config to RollingFileAppender, it didn't work either. Would it help to vanish your doubts if I say that extension of RollingFileAppender adds the function I want?